# Traefik API endpoint throwing 404 page not found with basic configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, toml

I am using `traefik` successfully to host web services locally on my `LAN`. I would like to look at the dashboard supplied by traefik in a secure way (Without using `insecure=true` config).

According to the [official documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/), the configuration should look like:

```
# Dynamic Configuration
[http.routers.my-api]
  rule = "Host(`traefik.example.com`)"
  service = "api@internal"
  middlewares = ["auth"]

[http.middlewares.auth.basicAuth]
  users = ["test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/"]

[api]
  dashboard = true
```

But when I run traefik with curl `curl 'http://traefik.example.com'` I am getting `404 page not found` and logs showing:

```
21/Jun/2022:14:40:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "-" 1 "-" "-" 0ms
```

The actual services though are working so there must be something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: What does your docker compose look like? My understanding is that the rule you run for the Traefik container itself might need adjusting. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/api/#configuration

Comment: got same issue. Have you fix the problem ?

Comment: No still not seeing the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/#secure-mode)

```
[api]
dashboard = true
```

needs to be part of the static configuration. You added it to the dynamic configuration